# Frobenius norm of $(U+U^T)-U^TU$

Tags: matrices

Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ an **upper triangular** real matrix.
Let $$S = R+R^T - R^TR,$$
which is obviously symmetric.

I'm interesting in getting an estimate of $\|S\|_F$, the Frobenius norm of $S$. Of course triangular inequality yields:
$$\left|\sqrt{2}\|R\|_F-\|R\|^2_F\right| \leq\|S\|_F\leq  \|R+R^T\|_F + \|R^TR\|_F \leq \sqrt{2}\|R\|_F+\|R\|^2_F.$$

Nonetheless for a diagonal matrix this estimate gets quite off for large matrices, so I'm wondering if it is possible to get a finer estimate than this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is useful, but if you rewrite $S$ as $I-(R-I)^T(R-I)$, then
\begin{align}
\|S\|_F\le\|I\|_F+\|R-I\|_F^2
&= \|I\|_F+\|I\|_F^2+\|R\|_F^2-2\operatorname{tr}(R)\tag{1}
\end{align}
and tie occurs when $R=I$. You may further relax the $-2\operatorname{tr}(R)$ in $(1)$ to $2\|I\|_F\|R\|_F$ using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but then the resulting inequality is not tight because tie occurs in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality here at $R=-I$ rather than at $R=I$.

Comment: Indeed this is tighter than my bound when letting the $\tr(R)$ as it is. I accept this answer.